# How do I create a Vue 3 custom element, including child component styles?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, shadow-dom

I tried Vue's `defineCustomElement()` to create a custom element, but the child component styles are not included in the shadow root for some reason.

I then tried to manually create my shadow root using the [native `Element.attachShadow()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) instead of using `defineCustomElement()` (based on a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-within-shadow-dom-1cz2e)), but then no styles were loaded at all:

**Code**: `main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

let treeHead = document.querySelector("#app");
let holder = document.createElement("div");
let shadow = treeHead.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
shadow.appendChild(holder);

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount(holder);
```

**Code** `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .loader("vue-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.shadowMode = true;
        return options;
      });
    config.module
      .rule("css")
      .oneOf("vue-modules")
      .use("vue-style-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.shadowMode = true;
        return options;
      });
    config.module
      .rule("css")
      .oneOf("vue")
      .use("vue-style-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.shadowMode = true;
        return options;
      });
  },
};
```

**Code** `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "shadow-root",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

**How I can create a custom element with all its styles in the shadow root?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That Vue config is not necessary in Vue 3. It was only needed by the dev server in Vue 2 to render the styles in custom elements.

Using `defineCustomElement()` is the recommended way to register custom elements. However, there's an open issue when using `defineCustomElement()`, where nested component styles are not rendered at all ([`@vuejs/vue-next#4462`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4662)).

A workaround is to import all components as custom elements so that the styles are attached to the component definition instead of being appended to `<head>`, then insert those styles into the DOM upon mounting:

- Enable [`vue-loader`'s `customElement` mode](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/tree/next#v16-only-options) in `vue.config.js`:

  ```js
  // vue.config.js
  module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.module
        .rule('vue')
        .use('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          options.customElement = true
          return options
        })
    }
  }
  ```

  Alternatively, rename all component filename extensions from `.vue` to `.ce.vue`.
- Create a utility function that wraps Vue's `defineCustomElement()` and does the following in a `setup()`:

  1. Create a temporary application instance that adds a [`mixin`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#mixin) for the `mounted` and `unmounted` lifecycle hooks.
  2. In the `mounted` hook, insert the component's own styles from `this.$.type.styles` into the DOM in a `<style>` tag. Do the same with the component definitions from the `this.$options.components` map.
  3. In the `unmounted` hook, remove the `<style>` tag that was inserted from `mounted`.
  4. Copy the temporary application instance's `_context` into the current application context from [`getCurrentInstance()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance).
  5. Return a render function for the component.

  ```js
  // defineCustomElementWithStyles.js
  import { defineCustomElement as VueDefineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

  const nearestElement = (el) => {
    while (el?.nodeType !== 1 /* ELEMENT */) el = el.parentElement
    return el
  }

  export const defineCustomElement = (component) =>
    VueDefineCustomElement({
      setup() {
        const app = createApp()
        1️⃣
        app.mixin({
          mounted() {
            const insertStyles = (styles) => {
              if (styles?.length) {
                this.__style = document.createElement('style')
                this.__style.innerText = styles.join().replace(/\n/g, '')
                nearestElement(this.$el).prepend(this.__style)
              }
            }

            2️⃣
            insertStyles(this.$?.type.styles)
            if (this.$options.components) {
              for (const comp of Object.values(this.$options.components)) {
                insertStyles(comp.styles)
              }
            }
          },
          unmounted() {
            this.__style?.remove() 3️⃣
          },
        })

        4️⃣
        const inst = getCurrentInstance()
        Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)

        5️⃣
        return () => h(component)
      },
    })
  ```
- Edit `public/index.html` to replace the `<div id="app">` with a custom element (e.g., named "`my-custom-element`"):

  *Before:*

  ```html
  // public/index.html
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  ```

  *After:*

  ```html
  // public/index.html
  <body>
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
  </body>
  ```
- Instead of `createApp()`, use the `defineCustomElement()` from above to create a custom element of your app:

  *Before:*

  ```js
  // main.js
  import { createApp } from 'vue'
  import App from './App.vue'
  createApp(App).mount('#app')
  ```

  *After:*

  ```js
  // main.js
  import { defineCustomElement } from './defineCustomElementWithStyles'
  import App from './App.vue'
  customElements.define('my-custom-element', defineCustomElement(App))
  ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-elements-with-styles-zhxyrx?file=src%2FdefineCustomElementWithStyles.js)