# Vue3 Styling Nested Single File Components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component

I am using Vue 3 to create some Web Components.  I would like to use Single File Components and be able to nest them and deploy, but the styling is missing on the child component.

[image]

I have simplified what I am trying to do with the following example.

MDivElement.ce.vue - a div that wraps MButton

```
<template>
  <div id="mdiv">
    MDiv
    <MButtonElement>MButton</MButtonElement>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MButtonElement from "./MButtonElement.ce.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    MButtonElement,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mdiv {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

MButtonElement.ce.vue - a simple Button

```
<template>
  <button id="mbutton">MButton</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mbutton {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-allen-xj74zt?file=/index.html)

My problem is that all the style is gone from the button when using `<m-div></m-div>`

**Can SFC be nested (with styles) and used as Web Components?**

I will compile using Vite and distribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of April 2022 and Vue 3.2 there is open bug [#4662](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4662) about this behavior, as in the question [How do I create a Vue 3 custom element, including child component styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69797635/1426891). One of the workarounds suggested in the bug is to make sure you are consuming the custom element by name in your template rather than using Vue and `import` to compose your components in custom elements.

You may need to update your SFC build plugin version so that it properly understands your `.ce.vue` extensions as custom elements that treat their styles differently. See the [SFC as Custom Element docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue):

> `defineCustomElement` also works with Vue Single-File Components (SFCs). However, with the default tooling setup, the `<style>` inside the SFCs will still be extracted and merged into a single CSS file during production build. When using an SFC as a custom element, it is often desirable to inject the `<style>` tags into the custom element's shadow root instead.
>
> The official SFC toolings support importing SFCs in "custom element mode" **(requires `@vitejs/plugin-vue@^1.4.0` or `vue-loader@^16.5.0`)**. An SFC loaded in custom element mode inlines its `<style>` tags as strings of CSS and exposes them under the component's `styles` option. This will be picked up by `defineCustomElement` and injected into the element's shadow root when instantiated.

---

Finally, as another potential workaround, you can to put the `<style>` within the element itself in order to accommodate the Shadow DOM technique that powers Web Components, or otherwise include the `styles` in the [defineCustomElement](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) Vue call specific to Custom Elements.

As in [the MDN web components documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM):

> You can affect the nodes in the shadow DOM in exactly the same way as non-shadow nodes — for example appending children or setting attributes, styling individual nodes using element.style.foo, or adding style to the entire shadow DOM tree inside a `<style>` element. The difference is that none of the code inside a shadow DOM can affect anything outside it, allowing for handy encapsulation.

In contrast, [Vue SFC scoping](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) rolls up the styles into the element itself, but applies the styles to the whole document with an arbitrary data element (`data-v-f3f3eg9` in the docs). Those styles are applied outside of the shadow dom, and consequently your styles set in SFC `<style>` tags aren't inherited inside of it.

Comment: ``:shadow`` and ``/deep/`` were Google only parties in Web Components V0, and never made it into the current standard V1. shadowParts are not the same but can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Comment: Hi Jeff - thanks for the detailed answer.  Unfortunately, I still cannot get the styling to work.  The css is not injected into the shadow dom no matter what I do.  Is there a working example of nested components with styling?  Thanks!

Comment: @mattjvincent I might have spoken too soon. Vue bug [#4662](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4662) notes that child component styles might not inherit, linked from [How do I create a Vue 3 custom element, including child component styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69797635/1426891). In retrospect maybe this question would be better marked as a duplicate of that one, would that be OK?

Comment: I would consider the question similar, however the provided answer doesn't work for compiling Vue SFC into distributable Web Components.  I want to compile the Vue components and use them in different applications (without a document root ot app root or whatever).

I want to be able to use MButtonElement <mbutton-element> and MDivElement <mdiv-element> by compiling these components into a distributable JS Library.  I can do this with LitElement and other frameworks, but unable to reproduce a working example with Vue.

<script "dist.js></script>
<mdiv-element></mdiv-element>

Comment: @mattjvincent I think you might have misunderstood the linked answer. The custom element just happens to be named `app-root` in the answer, but that was just an example name. The demo works as you describe (using the Custom Element by tag name).

Comment: @tony19 ... Actually you are right, it does work.  The link to the demo add some "globalComponents" parameter that is breaking for me.  While this does work, I notice the styles are included twice for subcomponents.  Once for the subcomponent itself but also on the parent component.  Thank you!

Comment: You can either mark as duplicate or I can accept the answer.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: @mattjvincent The style duplication appears to be fixed in a newer version of `vue`. Not sure what the bug was. I also fixed the `globalComponens` issue you mentioned in the demo.