# Vuetify + Web Component + ShadowDOM = Not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, web-component, shadow-dom

Has anyone created a custom web component in VueJS2 + Vuetify2 and managed to get ShadowDOM working?

I've tried two packages so far:

[vue-custom-element](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element) - This works but only when ShadowDOM is disabled.

[vue-web-component-wrapper](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper) - This package has ShadowDOM on by default and doesn't render any of the Vuetify components.

**Here is a screenshot of how the web component should look (this doesn't have ShadowDOM enabled):**

[image]

**And this is how it's rendering with ShadowDOM enabled:**
[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then provide some code. We're not a discussion forum and your question must be specific to your code.

Comment: You need to adoptedsheets on shadow dom : `shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];`.

Can i ask: **Why you want to use shadow dom when you use vue js**?

Comment: Hi @Anilkumar, I'm building this web component as a JS SDK that can then be implement on other 3rd party websites. The problem I'm having is that if those websites use VueJS, Tailwind Bootstrap, etc; the styles are conflicting. Do you have an example of adopted sheets?

Comment: All browser solution:`<template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vuetify src link">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstarp src link">
    </template>`. If you can avoid firefox, then read this web dev blog [css-module-scripts](https://web.dev/css-module-scripts/)

Comment: link tag inside template is locally scoped. It doesn't apply globally. Note,it is not render-blocking. This suffer from `FOUC`

Comment: `@layer` may also help you. Read more at MDN [@layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer)

Comment: maybe this is a solution? because Vue does not support children styles in custom element build yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797635/how-do-i-create-a-vue-3-custom-element-including-child-component-styles